# Most necessary #pragma-s?

Tags: c++, user-interface, command-line-interface, c-preprocessor

**Hi there, got a question.**

Im learning C++ half-o-year, and trying to understand preprocessor directives, so, I've learnt about #pragma, and know what #pragma once does.

I've seen many pro-C++ programmer's videos, where he is using more than this directive.

So, question is: What #pragma-s are most useful, which is necessary to use in GUI applications and which is necessary ones in CLI applications?

I've tried to search on the internet, but didn't found anything really useful.
*39 buried, 0 found...*

Thanks :)

Comment: Mostly, **none** of them are necessary. If you run into a situation where one of them is necessary, you'll learn it then. Remember they are different for every compiler

Comment: Not sure how professional those videos are and what they are trying to do, but I tend to minimize the use of the preprocessor  (to improve portability). This by the way extends into macro's (#define etc). For the few bits of C++/CLI I've written I never needed extra pragmas (like #pragma unmanaged), you either have the managed bits of code and the unmanaged bits of code and where needed you can pin memory explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Pragmas are usually created by compiler authors to do very specific things on their specific compiler, e.g. turning on and off compiler features, or tweaking the way the assembly code is generated. If you are in a situation where one is useful, you'll know it. For example, [Microsoft's `#pragma optimize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/optimize?view=msvc-170) lets you change the optimization level for a single function. If you want to do that for some reason, you might Google it and find this pragma.

Microsoft's pragmas are [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pragma-directives-and-the-pragma-keyword?view=msvc-170). GCC's pragmas are [documented here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pragmas.html) and [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html).

Although most of them are for specific unusual scenarios, there are a few that are generally useful on each compiler, so you're not wrong to have a look through the list just so you have an idea what's available.

Perhaps the most commonly used pragmas are `#pragma pack` ([GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Structure-Layout-Pragmas.html#Structure-Layout-Pragmas) [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/pack?view=msvc-170)) which affects the memory layout of structs, `#pragma warning` ([Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/warning?view=msvc-170)) / `#pragma GCC diagnostic` ([GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html#Diagnostic-Pragmas)) which lets you turn off certain compiler warnings in certain parts of the code, and `#pragma once` ([GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html) [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/once?view=msvc-170)) which is a shortcut for include guards that doesn't work on all compilers.